# Distribution of sample mean when samples are normal and correlated

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, mean

For the context of my question, let's say we have a n-dimensional multivariate normal random variable $\textbf{y} = (y_1,y_2,..,y_n)' \sim \textbf{N}(\mathbf{\mu,\Sigma})$ where $\mathbf{\mu} = (\mu,\mu,..,\mu)'$ and $\Sigma$ =
$\sigma^2\begin{pmatrix}
    1&\rho&...&\rho\\
    \rho&1&... &\rho\\
    \vdots & \vdots &&\vdots\\
    \rho&\rho&...&1
\end{pmatrix}$.

My question would be: what is the distribution of $\bar{y} = \frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n y_i$?

I know that there is a theorem that states that $\mathbf{a'y}\sim N(\mathbf{a'\mu,a'\Sigma a})$ if $\mathbf{y} \sim N(\mathbf{\mu,\Sigma})$ and $\mathbf{a}$ is any vector of constants, and in this case, I expressed $\bar{y} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{n}&\frac{1}{n}&...&\frac{1}{n}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\y_2\\ \vdots \\ y_d
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{n}&\frac{1}{n}&...&\frac{1}{n}
\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{a'y}$, where $\mathbf{a}' = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{n}&\frac{1}{n}&...&\frac{1}{n}
\end{pmatrix}$ .

Then the distribution of $\bar{y}$ would just be $N(\mathbf{a'\mu,a'\Sigma a})$ with the above specified $\mathbf{\mu}\; and \; \mathbf{\Sigma}$.

However I did not make use of the fact that the individual $y_i's$ are equicorrelated, thus I feel uneasy about this answer even though everything seems to be logically sound. May I gain some insight on this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. There is a specific form of $\mathbf\Sigma$ and $\boldsymbol\mu$, so if you include that in the final answer it would be fine. And since $\frac1n\sum y_i$ is going to have a normal distribution, you can just find its mean and variance directly.

Comment: Alright thanks!